# Linq2SQL DBML system Type for Varchar(1)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, dbml

I am using LINQ2SQL for DB Queries. I wrote a stored procedure and updated the DBML by drag and drop the stored procedure in `VS Server Explorer` to `DBML`.

But i got below mapping created by DBML designer

```
 <Parameter Name="p_in_gender" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(1)" />
```

We actually created `Varchar(1)` in a procedure and expected `Type="System.Char"` in dbml.

Could any one know what could be the problem with Linq2SQL designer?

Answer (score 1):

Char is not a supported Data type (annoying I know).  So it will always be mapped to a string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx